# get_page_by_title() doesn't return the post object if the title has inverted comma (')

Tags: php, codex

The question is self-explanatory. I have tried these so far.

I have a post named `John's Test` with post id 1.

In single.php, I tried,

```
$extraPostID = 1;
$extraContent = get_page_by_title(get_the_title($extraPostID), OBJECT, 'post');
var_dump($extraContent);
```

Result: NULL

But this works,

```
$extraPostID = 1;
$extraContent = get_page_by_title('John\'s Test', OBJECT, 'post');
var_dump($extraContent);
```

Returns the post object as intended.

So, I thought fine, let's add a slash to the title,

```
$extraPostID = 1;
$extraTitle = addslashes(get_the_title($extraPostID));
$extraContent = get_page_by_title($extraTitle, OBJECT, 'post');
var_dump($extraContent);
```

Returns NULL.

How about this

```
$extraPostID = 1
$str = html_entity_decode( get_the_title($extraPostID) );
$extraContent = get_page_by_title($str, OBJECT, 'post');
var_dump($extraContent);
```

Returns NULL.

So I am out of options. How do I make it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take 2 on my answer:

`get_the_title` uses the `the_title` filter, which turns your apostrophe into a right single quotation mark. When you then plug the resulting string into `get_page_by_title`, you don't get a match - because `’` is not the same as `'`.

So, bypass `the_title` filter completely:

```
$post = get_post( $extraPostID );
$extraContent = get_page_by_title( $post->post_title, OBJECT, 'post' );
```

Comment: Still NULL.
This problem can be reproduced by creating a new Wordpress site with TwentyTwentyone theme, renaming Hello world post to John's Test and then going to theme directory>template-parts>content>content-single.php and replacing the code there.
https://pastebin.com/eirn5N3c

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: That worked. Thanks for the answer.